# How to calculate rolling statistics in Scala

Tags: scala, collections

I have knowledge with respect to handling Dataframes in Python but I am facing the below problem while writing in scala.

```
case class Transaction(
      transactionId: String,
      accountId: String,
      transactionDay: Int,
      category: String,
      transactionAmount: Double)
```

I created a list like this:

```
  val transactions: List[Transaction] = transactionslines.map {           
      line => val split = line.split(',')
      Transaction(split(0), split(1), split(2).toInt, split(3),split(4).toDouble)
      }.toList
```

Contents of the list:

```
  Transaction(T000942,A38,28,EE,694.54)
  Transaction(T000943,A35,28,CC,828.57)
  Transaction(T000944,A26,28,DD,290.18)
  Transaction(T000945,A17,28,CC,627.62)
  Transaction(T000946,A42,28,FF,616.73)
  Transaction(T000947,A20,28,FF,86.84)
  Transaction(T000948,A14,28,BB,620.32)
  Transaction(T000949,A14,28,AA,260.02)
  Transaction(T000950,A32,28,AA,600.34)
```

Can anyone help me on how to calculate statistics for each account number for the previous five days of transactions, not including transactions from the day statistics are being calculated for. For example, on day 10 you should consider only the transactions from days 5 to 9 (this is called a rolling time window of five days). The statistics I need to calculate are:

•The total transaction value of transactions type “AA” in the previous 5 days per account

•The average transaction value of the previous 5 days of transactions per account

The output ideally should contain one line per day per account id and each line should contain each of the calculated statistics:

My code for the first 5 days looks like:

```
val a = transactions.
        filter(trans => trans.transactionDay <= 5).
        groupBy(_.accountId).
        mapValues(trans => (trans.map(amount => 
        amount.transactionAmount).sum/trans.map(amount => 
        amount.transactionAmount).size,trans.filter(trans => 
        trans.category == "AA").map(amount => 
        amount.transactionAmount).sum)
a.foreach{println}
```

I would like to know if there is any elegant way to calculate those statistics. Note that transcation day range from [1..29] so ideally I would like a code that calculate those rolling statistics up to 29th day and not only for the first 5 days.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Are you aware of the [sliding](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#sliding(size:Int,step:Int):Iterator[Repr]) method that is available on every sequence-like collection? It might be slightly less efficient than some prefix-sum-like approaches, but it's quick & simple to implement.

Comment: I don't think sliding is correct for this occasion as it consider a sliding window of fix size i.e 5 so if there is transaction for day 1,2,3,5,6 it will consider all of them as it has to take 5 elements whereas in reality I wooul like to consider only days up to 5th day. So it has to consider only days 1,2,3,5. Nevertheless, thanks a lot for your answer and your time!!

Comment: That wasn't an attempt to answer, it was just a comment. Ok, so, from your previous comment I see that your data is not equidistantly distributed in time, that's an important detail.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The collection contains transactions and it is possible for some day for a particular account no transaction to have been made. It is a tricky problem and that's make it more challenging to find an efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not 'elegant' but the following will provide the two desired statistics by `accountID` for a particular day:

```
def calcStats(ts: List[Transaction], day: Int): Map[String, (Double, Double)] = {
  // all transactions for date range, grouped by accountID
  val atsById = ts
   .filter(trans => trans.transactionDay >= day - 5 && trans.transactionDay < day)
   .groupBy(_.accountId)
  // "AA" transactions summmed by account id
  val aaSums = atsById.mapValues(_.filter(_.category == "AA"))
                      .mapValues(_.map(_.transactionAmount).sum)
  // sum of all transactions by account id
  val allSums = atsById.mapValues(_.map(_.transactionAmount).sum)
  // count of all transactions by account id
  val allCounts = atsById.mapValues(_.length)
  // output is Map(account id -> (aaSum, allAve))
  allSums.map { case (id, sum) => 
    id -> (aaSums.getOrElse(id, 0.0), sum / allCounts(id)) }
}
```

examples (using your provided data):

```
scala> calcStats(transactions, 30)
res13: Map[String,(Double, Double)] = Map(A32 -> (600.34,600.34), A26 -> 
(0.0,290.18), A38 -> (0.0,694.54), A20 -> (0.0,86.84), A17 -> (0.0,627.62), 
A42 -> (0.0,616.73), A35 -> (0.0,828.57), A14 -> (260.02,440.17))

scala> calcStats(transactions, 1)
res14: Map[String,(Double, Double)] = Map()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, really appreciate it. Is there any way to transform Map[String, (Double,Double)] back to Map[String, Double,Double] ?

Comment: @Andros perhaps you want a `Seq[String, (Double, Double)]`? If so just add a `toSeq`, i.e. `calcStats(transactions, 30).toSeq`

Answer (score 0):

```
object ScalaStatistcs extends App {
    import scala.io.Source
    // Define a case class Transaction which represents a transaction
    case class Transaction(
      transactionId: String,
      accountId: String,
      transactionDay: Int,
      category: String,
      transactionAmount: Double
  )
  // The full path to the file to import
    val fileName = "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\transactions.txt"
  // The lines of the CSV file (dropping the first to remove the header)
    val transactionslines = Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines().drop(1)
  // Here we split each line up by commas and construct Transactions
    val transactions: List[Transaction] = transactionslines.map { line =>
      val split = line.split(',')
      Transaction(split(0), split(1), split(2).toInt, split(3), split(4).toDouble)
  }.toList
  println(transactions)

  /* Data
   * transactionId  accountId   transactionDay  category    transactionAmount
T0001   A27 1   GG  338.11
T0002   A5  1   BB  677.89
T0003   A32 1   DD  499.86
T0004   A42 1   DD  801.81
T0005   A19 1   BB  14.42
T0006   A46 1   FF  476.88
T0007   A29 1   FF  439.49
T0008   A49 1   DD  848.9
T0009   A47 1   BB  400.42
T00010  A23 1   BB  416.36
T00011  A45 1   GG  662.98
T00012  A2  1   DD  775.37
T00013  A33 1   BB  185.4
T00014  A44 1   CC  397.19
T00015  A43 1   CC  825.05
T00016  A16 1   BB  786.14
T00017  A33 1   DD  352.64
T00018  A14 1   DD  733.77
T00019  A40 1   FF  435.5
T00020  A32 1   EE  284.34
T00021  A25 1   AA  291.76
   *
   */

  /* Question :1
   * Calculate the total transaction value for all transactions for each day.
     The output should contain one line for each day and each line should include the day and the total value
   */

  val question1 = transactions
    .groupBy(_.transactionDay)
    .mapValues(_.map(_.transactionAmount).sum)
  println(question1)

  /* Question :2
   * Calculate the average value of transactions per account for each type of transaction (there are seven in total).
     The output should contain one line per account, each line should include the account id and the average value
     for each transaction type (ie 7 fields containing the average values).
   */

  val question2 = transactions
    .groupBy(trans => (trans.accountId, trans.category))
    .mapValues(trans =>
      (trans.map(amount => amount.transactionAmount).sum / trans
        .map(amount => amount.transactionAmount)
        .size)
    )
  println(question2)

  /* Question :3
   * For each day, calculate statistics for each account number for the previous five days of transactions,
   * not including transactions from the day statistics are being calculated for. For example, on day 10 you
   * should consider only the transactions from days 5 to 9 (this is called a rolling time window of five days).
   * The statistics we require to be calculated are:
    The maximum transaction value in the previous 5 days of transactions per account
    The average transaction value of the previous 5 days of transactions per account
    The total transaction value of transactions types “AA”, “CC” and “FF” in the previous 5 days per account
   */

  var day = 0

  def day_factory(day: Int) =
    for (i <- 1 until day)
      yield i

  day_factory(30).foreach {
    case (i) => {
      day = i

      val question3_initial = transactions
        .filter(trans =>
          trans.transactionDay >= day - 5 && trans.transactionDay < day
        )
        .groupBy(_.accountId)
        .mapValues(trans => trans.map(day => day -> day.transactionAmount))
        .mapValues(trans =>
          (
            trans.map(t => day).max,
            trans.map(t => t._2).max,
            trans.map(t => t._2).sum / trans.map(t => t._2).size
          )
        )

      val question3_AA = transactions
        .filter(trans =>
          trans.transactionDay >= day - 5 && trans.transactionDay < day
        )
        .groupBy(_.accountId)
        .mapValues(trans =>
          trans
            .filter(trans => trans.category == "AA")
            .map(amount => amount.transactionAmount)
            .sum
        )

      val question3_CC = transactions
        .filter(trans =>
          trans.transactionDay >= day - 5 && trans.transactionDay < day
        )
        .groupBy(_.accountId)
        .mapValues(trans =>
          trans
            .filter(trans => trans.category == "CC")
            .map(amount => amount.transactionAmount)
            .sum
        )

      val question3_FF = transactions
        .filter(trans =>
          trans.transactionDay >= day - 5 && trans.transactionDay < day
        )
        .groupBy(_.accountId)
        .mapValues(trans =>
          trans
            .filter(trans => trans.category == "FF")
            .map(amount => amount.transactionAmount)
            .sum
        )

      val question3_final = question3_initial.map { case (k, v) =>
        (k, v._1) -> (v._2, v._3, question3_AA(k), question3_CC(
          k
        ), question3_FF(k))
      }
      println(question3_final)
    }
  }

}
```